# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }

Tags: javascript, asp.net, highcharts

When I debug my code in Google Chrome, I have a red text saying

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }.

I don't understand why and where this is coming from. This is the code from the source console:

```
var chart = $('#container1').highcharts();chart.series[0].setData(array2);chart.redraw(); });    //]]>
```

- Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }

  ```
  </script>
  ```

Code in vb.net

```
Dim script As String
    script = _
        "var chart = $('#container1').highcharts();" & _
        '"chart.series[0].setData(array2);" & _
        "chart.redraw();" & _
    " }); "


    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock( _
        Me, _
        GetType(Page), _
        "container1", _
        script, _
        True)
```

i have a Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }, ub tge vb.net code

Comment: Well, near the end of the line you have `});`. That's where it is coming from. If you'd [format your code properly](http://jsbeautifier.org/), you would probably find the problem yourself.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a syntax error.

Comment: i removed it, but error is still there.

Comment: Maybe a caching issue. Disable caching and/or force reload the page.

Comment: Why is your code suddenly different?

Comment: before i showed the code from the source control on google chrome, but this is the code in the javascript, this is how its actually is shown as.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33070/discussion-between-m-ali-and-felix-kling)

Comment: Those look like two different pieces of code. The second one does not include `chart.redraw();` for example. There is no syntax error in the second piece.

Comment: updated,actually the error is comming from the vb.net rather than javascrip, i have edited the code.

Comment: Are you saying that it is not JavaScript that throws the error but your vb.net code? The script you create still seems to contain `});` which is wrong if that's the whole script. You have edited and changed your question so many times now that it does not make sense to follow it anymore.

Comment: updated question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17524352/uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-vb-net

Comment: See, but the problem is still the same, you had the trailing `});`. The other error you get is a runtime error and has nothing to do with original error.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var chart = $('#container1').highcharts();

    chart.series[0].setData(array2);

    chart.redraw();
});
```

or this:

```
var chart = $('#container1').highcharts();

chart.series[0].setData(array2);

chart.redraw();
```

This will solve the error you get.

Comment: it wont work, because its not connected to the button, if you see the edited code above, this is the javascript code.