# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token } vb.net

Tags: vb.net, syntax-error

When I debug my code in Google Chrome, I have a red text saying

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }.

I don't understand why and where this is coming from. This is the code from the source console:

```
var chart = $('#container1').highcharts();chart.series[0].setData(array2);chart.redraw(); });    //]]>
```

- Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }

  ```
  </script>
  ```

Code in vb.net

```
Dim script As String
    script = _
        "var chart = $('#container1').highcharts();" & _
        '"chart.series[0].setData(array2);" & _
        "chart.redraw();" & _
    " }); "


    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock( _
        Me, _
        GetType(Page), _
        "container1", _
        script, _
        True)
```

i have a Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }, ub tge vb.net code

updated code:

```
   Dim script As String
script = _
    "var chart = $('#container1').highcharts();" & _
    "chart.series[0].setData(array2);" & _
    "chart.redraw();" & _
 "}" & _
 ")" & _
 ";"
```

error:

```
 var chart = $('#container1').highcharts();chart.series[0].setData(array2);chart.redraw(); });//]]>
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }
</script>
```

Comment: The problem is not in vb. Do you have any other errors in console? Can we see it live? I hope #container1 exists on your site and chart is already rendered in that conatiner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
       Dim script As String
    script = _
        "var chart = $('#container1').highcharts();" & _
        "chart.series[0].setData(array2);" & _
        "chart.redraw();" & _
     "}" & _
     ")" & _
     ";"
```

Comment: still error
var chart = $('#container1').highcharts();chart.series[0].setData(array2);chart.redraw(); });//]]>
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }
</script>

Answer (score 2):

You can replace `" }); "` with `""`.

Comment: when i did that, i get a new error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'series' of undefined :/

Comment: @mali: That means `.highcharts` does not return a value. I suggest to read the documentation to learn how to set it up properly: http://docs.highcharts.com/#your-first-chart. It might also to read about how jQuery works: http://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/.

Comment: the problem is in vb.net, i still have the error, Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }

Comment: @mali: In your earlier comment you said you get a `Uncaught TypeError`. What is it now?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have unbalanced curly brackets.  Did you copy and paste your script from somewhere?

Try this and let us know if it gets rid of the error:

```
Dim script As String
script = _
    "var chart = $('#container1').highcharts();" & _
    "chart.series[0].setData(array2);" & _
    "chart.redraw();"
```